# I cannot bind the props with data in vuetify components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding, vuetify.js

I want to bind the data with the props in my vuetify components. However, it has no effect. I tried it with a v-skeleton-loader and v-list and both yielded no results. What might be the problem?

Here is the code:

```
<v-list
      style="max-height: 275px"
      class="overflow-y-auto"
      dense
      :disabled="loading"
    >
      <v-list-item-group v-model="x" color="primary">
        <v-list-item v-for="(knittingtype, i) in knittingTypes" :key="i">
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-skeleton-loader ref="skeleton" type="list-item" loading>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="knittingtype.name"></v-list-item-title
            ></v-skeleton-loader>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>
```

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    x : null, 
    loading: true,
  }),
}
```

Comment: The variable `x` is set to `null` and is never updated (from your current code), so the `v-list-item-group` component can't show up

Comment: That does not affect my code. It changes with a click on the list item. My question is more about the props :disabled="loading" . As you can see, that has not anything to do with x.

Answer (score 0):

The binding on the `v-list` is correct , you probably just never updated that `loading` variable !
As for the `<v-skeleton-loader>` , I'm not sure what you wanted to do , but using
`<v-skeleton-loader loading></v-skeleton-loader>` is the same as `<v-skeleton-loader loading="true"></v-skeleton-loader>` .
If you also want to bind that to the 'loading' variable , you should do it the same way as what you did for the `v-list` : `:loading="loading"`

Comment: Unfortunately :loading="loading" does not work. That's the main reason why I asked this question.

Comment: I haven't worked with `<v-skeleton-loader>` that much but based on the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/skeleton-loaders/)  , for `<v-skeleton-loader>` `loading` "A value of false will only work when there is content in the default slot".

Comment: As for the `<v-list>` if you also used `:loading="loading"` , you should know that `loading` is not a valid attribute for `<v-list>`. if you used anything else , it is always the same format : `:attribute="variable"`.